# How to update a TextView of Fragment inside other class

Tags: android, class, textview, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to update a TextView inside my Fragment through a button click on my RecyclerView. I tried through passing Context but my app crashed when clicked the button if I use Context. please help me to do it.

Here is my RecyclerAdapter

```
public class CartRecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartRecycleAdapter.RecycleViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<CartDataProvider> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
Context CTX;
public CartRecycleAdapter(ArrayList<CartDataProvider> arraylist, Context ctx){
    this.arraylist = arraylist;
    this.CTX = ctx.getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public RecycleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.modelcart, parent,false);
    RecycleViewHolder recycleViewHolder = new RecycleViewHolder(view);
    return recycleViewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecycleViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final CartDataProvider homeCycleDataProvider = arraylist.get(position);

    holder.ItemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);
    holder.TXV_ItemName.setText(homeCycleDataProvider.getItemName().toString());
    holder.TXV_PastPrice.setText(String.valueOf(homeCycleDataProvider.getPastPrice()).toString());
    holder.TXV_FixedPrice.setText(String.valueOf(homeCycleDataProvider.getFixedPrice()).toString());
    holder.TXV_Quantity.setText(Integer.valueOf(homeCycleDataProvider.getQuantity()).toString());
    holder.ratingBar.setRating(homeCycleDataProvider.getRating());

    holder.BTN_QuantityPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int x = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            CartDataProvider homeCycleDataProvider = arraylist.get(x);
            int quantity = homeCycleDataProvider.getQuantity();

            homeCycleDataProvider.setQuantity(++quantity);
            holder.TXV_Quantity.setText(String.valueOf(homeCycleDataProvider.getQuantity()));
            TextView textView = (TextView) ((MainActivity)CTX).findViewById(R.id.txt_total_amount);
            textView.setText("ok");
        }
    });
    holder.BTN_QuantityMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int x = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            CartDataProvider homeCycleDataProvider = arraylist.get(x);
            int quantity = homeCycleDataProvider.getQuantity();

            if(quantity != 0){
                homeCycleDataProvider.setQuantity(--quantity);
                holder.TXV_Quantity.setText(String.valueOf(homeCycleDataProvider.getQuantity()));
                TextView textView = (TextView) ((MainActivity)CTX).findViewById(R.id.txt_total_amount);
                textView.setText("ok");

            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arraylist.size();
}

public static class RecycleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView ItemImage;
    TextView TXV_ItemName, TXV_PastPrice, TXV_FixedPrice, TXV_Percentage,TXV_Quantity;
    ImageButton BTN_QuantityMinus, BTN_QuantityPlus;
    RatingBar ratingBar;


    public RecycleViewHolder(View view){

        super(view);

        ItemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        TXV_ItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        TXV_PastPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.past_price);
        TXV_FixedPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fixed_price);
        TXV_Percentage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.percentiage);
        ratingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        TXV_Quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txv_quantity);
        BTN_QuantityMinus = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity_minus);
        BTN_QuantityPlus = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity_plus);

    }
}
```

Here is my Fragment.java

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);

    TXT_TotalAmout = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_total_amount);
    TXT_Quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txv_quantity);

    CartItemRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_recycler_id);

    int i =0;
    for (String name : itemname){

        CartDataProvider cartDataProvider = new CartDataProvider(itemname[i], imageurl[i],
                rating[i],pastprice[i],fixedprice[i],Quantity);

        arrayList.add(cartDataProvider);

        TotalPrice += fixedprice[i];
        i++;
    }

    adapter = new CartRecycleAdapter(arrayList,getContext());
    CartItemRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    CartItemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    CartItemRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    CartItemRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Rather than updating that TextView directly in your ViewHolder, a better pattern might be to pass in some callback to your RecyclerAdapter (which your Fragment for example implements)....that way your RecyclerAdapter isn't coupled to the particular fragment you're using.

Answer (score 0):

declare your `textview` as `static` in your `Fragment Class`

```
public static TextView TXT_TotalAmout, TXT_Quantity;
```

now in your `Recycler view`

```
MyFragClass.TXT_TotalAmount.setText("Your Amount");
MyFragClass.TXT_Quantity.setText("Your Amount");
```